# What does the translation "God enhanced Jesus" mean in Philippians 2:9 (Wycliffe Bible)?

Tags: philippians

> 9 For which thing **God enhanced him**, and gave to him a name that is
>   above all name; [For which thing and **God enhanced him**, and gave to
>   him a name that is above all names;]
>
> Philippians 2:9 Wycliffe Bible (WYC)

What does the translation "God enhanced Jesus" mean in Philippians 2:9 (*Wycliffe Bibl*e)?

Answer (score 1):

It means that God exalted him above all others, just as God gave him a name that is above all others. The Wycliffe Bible uses the word "enhanced," which is just another way of saying exalted.

[Enhance](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enhance?s=t):

> verb (used with object), enhanced, enhancing.
>
> 1. **to raise to a higher degree**; intensify; magnify: *The candelight enhanced her beauty.*
> 2. to raise the value or price of: *Rarity enhances the worth of old coins.*

[Exalt](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exalt?s=t):

> verb (used with object)
>
> 1. **to raise in rank, honor, power, character, quality, etc.**; elevate: *He was exalted to the position of president.*
> 2. to praise; extol: *to exalt someone to the skies.*
> 3. to stimulate, as the imagination: *The lyrics of Shakespeare exalted the audience.*
> 4. to intensify, as a color: *complementary colors exalt each other.*
> 5. Obsolete. to elate, as with pride or joy.